# Irreducibility of the Sylvester resultant

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, resultants

If $r$ and $s$ are positive integers, $R$ a commutative ring and $a_0,\dots,a_r$, $b_0,\dots,b_s$ independent variables, we can consider the polynomials $f=\sum_{i=0}^ra_iX^i$ and $g=\sum_{j=0}^sb_iX^j$ in $R[a_0,\dots,a_r,b_0,\dots,b_s][X]$ and then compute their Sylvester resultant $$R_{r,s}=\mathsf{res}_{r,s}(f,g)\in R[a_0,\dots,a_r,b_0,\dots,b_s].$$

It is a result well-known among people that know such things that $R_{r,s}$ is an irreducible element in $R[a_0,\dots,a_r,b_0,\dots,b_s]$ if $R$ is a field of characteristic zero; see, for example, the answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221891/reducibility-of-resultants) and/or, of course, the Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky book on resultants. In that answer, Vesselin Dimitrov tells us that in general over a field resultants are a power of an irreducible, but I think I can prove in that case that it is actually irreducible (so that maybe he means general resultants?) and my argument seems to work over a ring $R$ with prime nilradical (that is, with irreducible spectrum).

> Is $R_{r,s}$ irreducible for what rings $R$?

Comment: One has to exclude the cases $r=0$ and $s=0$ because $\operatorname{res}_{r,0}(f,b_0) = b_0^r$ and $\operatorname{res}_{0,s}(a_0,g) = a_0^s$.

Comment: In many such question, e.g., the  one linked below, the question is not about irreducibility of resultants of polynomials whose coefficients are each variables, but results of polynomials "derived" from some other "universal" object: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156586/irreducibility-of-a-resultant-of-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-a-characteristic-po

Comment: If $R=R_1 \times R_2$ for some integral domains $R_1,R_2$ then the resultant $R_{r,s}$ over $R$ is reducible for a rather silly reason: using the isomorphism $R[a_i,b_j] = R_1[a_i,b_j] \times R_2[a_i,b_j]$ we have $R_{r,s} = (R_{r,s},1) \cdot (1,R_{r,s})$ and none of the factors is a unit. Irreducibility is not well-behaved for such rings, one may try to replace it by some kind of local irreducibiliy (note $\operatorname{Spec} R = \operatorname{Spec} R_1 \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} R_2$) as in the answers of this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63899/